# How to have a table of content for python script inside vs code like in jupyter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I like jupyter lab since it has a table of content when using markdown cells. so for a big script file, it is easy to navigate the code using table of content. Now if I convert an ipynb file into a normal py file, inside vs code, is it possible to have a table of content like in jupyter? any possible solution inside vs code?

Thank you so much for sharing your idea.

Comment: Does the [**OUTLINE**](https://imgur.com/jdaTNub) view help?

Comment: Thanks Du. Outline in my case basically are functions and variable. It kinds of help at least. Is it possible to make some block comments like """ Callback""" as outline ? Thanks

Comment: The use of markdown in jupyter also displays the directory structure in the outline view. But markdown and python scripts are obviously different. The outline will show all the classes, modules, methods, properties, variables, etc. in the python script. As code, it can't be displayed like Chapter 1, Chapter 2.

If you just want to include the comments, how do you think it will recognize and display the name in the list? And with the outline view as the view that shows the structure of the code, it doesn't seem surprising that comments are not shown.

Comment: If you have completely different display requirements, you can describe it in more detail, or submit a feature request on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v1.0.0 you can create a Table of Content in a View in the Explorer Bar (Next to **OUTLINE**)

Example Python file:

```py
"""Awesome Python book Code"""

# toc Chapter 1
def foo1():
  pass

# toc Chapter 2
def bar2():
  pass
# toc -- Chapter 2.1
def bar2Input():
  pass
# toc -- Chapter 2.2
def bar2Draw():
  pass

# toc Chapter 3
def foobar3():
  pass
```

Use the following setting:

```json
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "python": [
      {
        "find": "#\\s*toc\\s*(.+)",
        "filePath": "${fileBasename}",
        "lineNr": "position.start.line+1",
        "charPos": "1",
        "label": "$1",
        "allowCurrentFile": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "html-related-links.alwaysShow": true
```

This gives the following view:

- Chapter 1
- Chapter 2
- -- Chapter 2.1
- -- Chapter 2.2
- Chapter 3

If you click on one of the lines in the tree the cursor is moved to the line after the toc-comment. Adjust the `lineNr` expression if needed.

You can change the `# toc` comment lines and adjust the Regular Expression of the `find` property.

Comment: Thank you rioV8, that is very exciting. I copy the setting in settings.json file, and add few #toc chapter like what you did then restart vs code.  Unfortunately I didn't see the TOC next to outline. could you please help? I appreciate it

Comment: @roudan Maybe you have to set: `html-related-links.alwaysShow` to `true`

Comment: Thanks  do I just add it to settings.Jason file like this  html-related-links.alwaysShow=True? Do I need to use double quotes around html-related-links.alwaysShow? Thx

Comment: @roudan see the update answer on what to add to `settings.json` (global or workspace)

Comment: Thanks rioV8, I did change and also use your python script file. I still cannot see the table of content next to OUTLINE.  Not sure where I did wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It does work, [here](https://imgur.com/xUpB2vz) is the effect I tested and my [workspace **settings.json**](https://imgur.com/BspvOUo).

Comment: @JialeDu thanks for check and comment with images

Comment: @roudan have you disabled the display of the **RELATED LINKS** view with the **EXPLORER** bar top menu `...`

Comment: yes, it works now, Thank you JialeDu for your screenshot. The error I made was I copy the above setting outside the  big { }. Thank you rioV8 for this awesome tricks. It really made my night!!!!  I love it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi rioV8, can I have one more question, is it possible to have 2-3 levels of table of content like heading1, heading 2, heading 3 etc in word document?  Thanks

Comment: @roudan Can you create an issue at the github repo and explain how you want to type the comments and how you expect the display in the view